# For Ising models on finite graphs, is the gradient of Z (w/r/t coupling and field) easier to compute than Z?

Tags: statistical-physics, mp.mathematical-physics, pr.probability, computational-complexity, graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, edgeset $E$, $\mathcal{X}=\{1,-1\}^n$. The partition function of the spin-1/2 Ising model on $G$ is

$$Z(J,h)=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}} \exp\left(J \sum_{(i,j)\in E} x_i x_j + h \sum_i x_i\right)$$

and its gradient with respect to the coupling and applied field is

$$\nabla Z(J,h)=\left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial J} Z, \frac{\partial}{\partial h} Z \right ).$$

We are interested in computing these quantities to some pre-determined finite precision. Computing $Z$ is [hard](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5584) in general, but [easy](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.5486) in special cases, like when $|J|$ is small relative to average degree of the graph.

What can we say about relative hardness of computing $\nabla Z$?

Comment: The angle brackets threw me off for a second when I tried to imagine an inner product there.  I guess other notation might be subject to the same problem though.

Comment: What's the standard notation for vector written out explicitly?

Comment: Maybe if you write $\in \mathbb{R}^2$ ?  It's not a big deal though.

Comment: If you are going to use angle brackets, you should surely use \langle and \rangle rather than the less-than and greater-than symbols.

Comment: Can you explain your notation, please?  Does that indicate the correlation function of $\partial Z/\partial J$ and $\partial Z/\partial h$ with respect to the Gibbs measure?

Comment: He means just the pair of numbers $\partial Z/\partial J$ and $\partial Z/\partial h$.  That's what my confusion was about above too.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that "physically" these quantities (up to sign) are the average energy and average magnetization of the graph.

Comment: See also http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/complexity-of-linearized-ising-model-at-0

Comment: That was me asking if Z'(0,0) is as easy to compute as Z(0,0) ... which it is